# Post a value of the form to the database

Tags: php, mysql

This might be really a  very easy one for many of you but m stuck here.i have a two files frame1.php and frame.php.The code for frame1.php is

```
 <?php
include "localhost.php";
                if(isset($_POST['button']))
                {
                    $query = $_POST['class'];
                    $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM books
                        WHERE class = '$query'") or die(mysql_error());

                        echo 'Class:-'."".$query;
                        ?>
                        <table width="500" border="1">
              <tr>

                <td width="96" align="center">Name</td>
                <td width="107" align="center">Class:-</td>
                <td width="109" align="center">Price:-</td>
                 <td width="43" align="center">Quantity:-</td>
                 <td width="112" align="center">Select quantity</td>
                <td width="112" align="center">Total amount</td>

                <td width="112" align="center">Add:-</td>
              </tr>


         <?php
                    if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0)
                    {
                        while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results))
                        {
                            ?>

              <tr><td align="center"><input name="items" type="text" disabled="disabled" id="itm" value="<?php echo $results['items'];?>" />                  </td>
              <td  align="center"><input name="class" type="text" disabled="disabled" id="cls" value="<?php echo $results['class'];?>" /></td>
                <td  align="center"><input name="price" type="text" disabled="disabled" id="prc" value="<?php echo $results['price'];?>" /></td>
                <td  align="center"><input name="quantity" type="text" disabled="disabled" id="quan" value="<?php echo $results['quantity'];?>" /></td>
                <td  align="center"><select name="select_quantity" onchange="getquant(this.value);"><option>Select quantity</option>
                <?php  for ($i=1;$i<=$results['quantity'];$i++)
                                                    {
                                                echo '<option>'. htmlspecialchars($i) . "</option>\n";
                                                    }

                                               ?></select></td>
                <td  align="center"><input name="total" type="text" value="" id="total" disabled="disabled"  /><br /></td>



                <td align="center"><a target="frame3" href="frame3.php?var=<?php echo $results['items'];?>">Add</a></td>
              </tr>

        <?php
                        }
                    }
                    else
                        {
                            echo "There is no record.";
                        }

                    }

            ?>
            <?php




            ?>
          </table>
```

the code for frame3.php is

```
<?php
$name=$_GET['var'];
include "localhost.php";
$sql="insert into temp_data(items,class,category,price,date,quantity,select_quantity,total) values('$_POST[items]','$_POST[class]','$_POST[category]','$_POST[price]','$date','$_POST[quantity]','$_POST[select_quantity]','$_POST[total]') where items=$name ";
    mysql_query($sql);
$query1="select * from temp_data";
$results=mysql_query($query1);
            ?>
```

Now i am trying to enter the values that i receive from the textbox in frame1.php into the database temp_data but i am getting an error of undefined index in frame3.php.
What may be wrong?????

Comment: **Imediately stop using this code. It is vulnerable to SQL injection.** [**Stop using `mysql_*` functions**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Answer (score 0):

use POST instead of GET - strip slashes, real_escape_, etc... and mysqli as mysql_ has been deprecated as of PHP-5. Try KISS methodology with php. get it functional get it secure get it pretty.